# A word meaning 'to throw things out too quickly'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

*It would be [adjective] to dismiss president's new policy, as purely politic playing, it appears he has genuine intentions to improve the well being of the poor.*

What adjective would be correct to mean that things were dismissed too quickly?

Comment: It depends on how the author likes to describe the nature and possible effect of doing it "too quickly." Each of the possible expressions has a different implication and a different degree of emphasis. You need to consider your own context and decide accordingly.

Comment: I have feeling that you want an equivalent to **dismiss too quickly** and not just **too quickly** like what they answered you.

Answer (score 2):

[hasty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hasty): adjective

> - moving or acting with haste; speedy; quick; hurried.
> - unduly quick; precipitate; rash: a hasty decision.

[rash](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rash): adjective

> acting or tending to act too hastily or without due consideration.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possibilities: *premature, rash, precipitate, untimely, ill-timed, inopportune, overhasty*.

Comment: If the person doing the dismissing was acting with intent to disrupt I suppose one could also use 'pre-emptive' or 'pre-emptory'.